# Error authenticating after migrating to Spring Security 6 - (Missing client_secret)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, migrating

I've been migrating my microsservices to **Springboot 3.0.2**, and now i have to use the **spring security version 6**, but i'm facing a problem when the request build the request body to OAuth Provider in background, when i see the logs i realized that field client_secret is always forgotten, that why, client_secret is missed in request and Oauth Provider return a **401 UNAUTHORIZED** with reason:

```
Decoded [{error=true, type=invalid_client, message=Missing client_secret parameter, details={name=OAuth2Error, message=Missing client_secret parameter, headers={WWW-Authenticate=Basic realm="Service"}, code=401, error=invalid_client, error_description=Missing client_secret parameter}}]
```

Its important to say, before migrating to spring security 6, in other words, when i used the spring securty 5.X it was working successfully!

1. [I saw the application can retrieve the values from enviroment variables correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqMpy.png)
2. [This log shows that field client_secret was ignored.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulIOU.png)
3. [Here we can see a successfully request by previous spring security version, the field client_secret was present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK4El.png)
4. [Here is my spring configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4nyD.png)
5. [This is my WebSecurityConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQEhV.png)

I tried to rewrite the WebSecurityConfig in several ways, but no one works.

Comment: Please share your code, not pictures of your code. Also, have you reviewed the migration guide for [OAuth deprecations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/oauth2.html#_clientauthenticationmethod)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can replace `post` with `client_secret_post` in your `application.yml`.